# regridding unregular grid to regular

Tags: r, matrix, vectorization, raster, map-projections

I have satellite images in EASE 2.0 projection and want to reproject them to a regular WGS84 0.25 degree grid. I have tried several options, e.g. rasterize them to an empty raster with my desired dimensions, but would like more control over the process, since this only allowed for bilinear and nearest neighbour interpolation.

Currently I read the data and the corresponding longitude,longitude and then loop through each pixel lat/lon in my desired output grid computing the distance to all measurements in the original file. If the distance is smaller than 0.5 pixel spacing (18km, I convert the lat,lon distances to distances in meters) I use that measurement. The output pixel is the average of all measurements within that distance (later I will expand to weighted average based on distance). Unfortunately how I currently do it is very slow. Are there any good possibilities to speed things up, e.g. avoid the double loop?

```
    library(raster)
    library(rgdal)

    #input data, x=longitude, y=latitude, z=measurements
    #r
    # EXAMPLE DATA https://files.fm/u/qshgpzjp
    load ('image.Rdata')
    r[r == -9999] = NaN

    #output lat,lons on 0.25 degree grid
    long = seq(-180,180,0.25)
    lat = seq(90,-90,-0.25)
    long = long+0.125
    lat = lat-0.125
    lat = lat[1:720]
    long = long[1:1440]

    #matrix to put output in
    out.m = matrix(data = NaN, nrow=1440, ncol=720)


    #double loop over lon,lat of output grid
    for (lo in 1:1440) {
      for (la in 1:720) {

        # 2 columns with lon,lat
        xy = cbind(r[,1],r[,2])

        # convert lon,lat of original data to meters
        xy_meter <- project(xy,"+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

        #lon,lat of current output pixel to be computed
        lonlat = cbind(long[lo],lat[la])

        #convert lon,lat of current output pixel to meters
        xy_la = project(lonlat, "+proj=cea +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=30 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371228 +b=6371228 +units=m +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")

        #compute distance and select original measurements within 18000m both in x and y direction, compute average of valid measurements
        dlo = xy_la[,1] - xy_meter[,1]
        dla = xy_la[,2] - xy_meter[,2]

        blb1 = dlo < 18000 & dlo > -18000
        blb2 = dla < 18000 & dla > -18000

        blb = blb1 & blb2


        check = max(blb)
        if (check < 1) next

        valids = r[blb,3]
        out.m[lo,la] = mean(r[blb,3],na.rm=T)

      }
      print(lo)
    }
```

Comment: Unclear why you would want a regular grid in longitude/latitude, but the key here is to vectorize, removing the loops. Do you have a link to an example file?

Comment: https://files.fm/u/qshgpzjp

this is an example file in r format. Unfortunately I need to reproject to a regular grid to compare the data to model data on a regular 0.25 degree grid.

Comment: I guess the most obvious improvement would be to move the conversion from lon,lat to meters outside the double loop. However the main issue how to speed up / get rid of the loop remains.